# Write equation such that align top of number

Tags: equations, numbering, align

How to write equation such that align top of number as picture below?

[image]

I try to type a code as follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=2.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 
        $\begin{aligned}
            \nu_{\diamond A}(0)&=\nu_A(0)=1
        \end{aligned}$
        \item $\begin{aligned}
            \mu_{\diamond A}(x+y)&=1-\nu_A(x+y)
            \leq 1-T(\nu_{A}(x),\nu_{A}(y))
            = C(1-\nu_{A}(x),1-\nu_{A}(y))\\
            &= C(\mu_{\diamond A}(x),\mu_{\diamond A}(y))
        \end{aligned}$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

It gives me

[image]

I don't know how to do write equation such that the equation is align top of number. So, how to make it?

Comment: Use `\begin{aligned}[t]` in the second `\item`.

Comment: It works. Thanks!